# SmartEdit setup in spartacus

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to setup SmartEdit in our spartacusstorefront.  We use a customized extension which is based on spartacussampledataaddon.

Followed in the instructions in:  https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/

But in smartedit, we get this error:
No component factory found for SmarteditElementComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents

Any pointers

Comment: See if this will help you: https://answers.sap.com/answers/13005689/view.html

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow this.  But for the step:
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames=smarteditaddon -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=<your_custom_storefront>
which storefront should I select as spartacus is a headless storefront.

Comment: I followed the additional steps.  
1.  Added the required extensions for smartedit.
2. ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="smarteditaddon" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="electronicsstore"
3.  Update system of extensions included earlier.
4.  ant npminstall
5.  ant build
6.  Start server.
Still the same error.

Comment: I think you can skip the addoninstall for storefront.

Comment: what I also noticed is, there is a SmarteditElementComponent in hybris storefront and it is added to @NgModule.entryComponents.  I wonder why an error gets reported.

Comment: If you are using Spartacus, you can remove the Hybris storefront from your localextensions.xml. It doesn't make sense to have the JSP storefront if you have Spartacus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215353/discussion-between-mahesh-and-geffchang).

Comment: @geffchang off topic, but there could actually be cases where one likes to mix a Spartacus storefront and accelerator storefront on a single platform. Either in a multi-site setup, where some brands/stores are running other storefront, or in case customers transition to Spartacus in steps.

Comment: @tobi-or-not-tobi Thanks for the note. I suppose that is also possible, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

This error actually does not relate to Spartacus, it's a SmartEdit edit error instead. The SmartEdit team is not watching this channel, so Id recommend to use existing help/support/consultant channels to fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I have posted to answers.sap.com:  https://answers.sap.com/questions/13070562/smartedit-setup-in-spartacus.html.  Awaiting their response.